# Torrc file is blank, or has few details

Tags: configuration

I am trying to edit the torrc file, but on my Windows version of Tor the torrc file is blank. I have also looked at Tor on my Mac OSX and Linux machines and the torrc file there are only 6 lines of text as below:

```
# This file was generated by Tor; if you edit it, comments will not be preserved
# The old torrc file was renamed to torrc.orig.1 or similar, and Tor will ignore it

DataDirectory Home/User/Desktop/Browser/Tor Browser/Data/Tor
GeoIPFile Home/User/Desktop/Browser/Tor Browser/Data/Tor/geoip
GeoIPv6File Home/User/Desktop/Browser/Tor Browser/Data/Tor/geoip6   
HiddenServiceStatistics 0
```

I have added details to the blank torrc file such as:

```
ExitNodes {DE}
Strict Nodes 1
```

And this works for restricting the exit nodes.

I would like to change more technical details on the torrc file so why is my torrc file blank, or only have a 6 lines of text in it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Tor has alot of "pre-configured defaults" shipped with it, and most of them are very well-fitting for most of users. Actually, you can run Tor even without a `torrc` file at all! So - it's no problem, that your file has 2-4 or 6 lines.

Answer (score 0):

Tors default configuration is tucked away in a different file. Most users, use the regular torrc file to override the options they need changed.

If you are using tor with the browser, you can find the torrc-defaults file in `Browser/TorBrowser/Data/Tor`

Comment: Thanks for your response. Having looked in the torrc-defaults file it doesn't contain any of the commented-out section about Tor Hidden Services that are described on the page https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-hidden-service.html.en step two. Do I just find a default file online?

Comment: Neat! I have been planning to host my blog as a hidden service for a long time. Anyways, most relay/hs operators have a tor instance that runs independently on a different machine. 

In your case, since your tor is bundled with tbb its configuration files are customized for that. 

But that shouldn't stop you from experimenting. The tutorial you were reading is referring to something like [this](https://gitweb.torproject.org/tor.git/tree/src/config/torrc.sample.in). 

Feel free to use the file as a reference. Infact, I used the same file to configure my tor relay too. Good luck!